# Button Outside GridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

1 - There is GridView and one button OUTSIDE the GridView

2 - How can i get and specific value from this grid using the button

Aspx:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCalc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="tx_desc" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnGetValue" runat="server" OnClick="btnGetValue_Click" />
<asp:Label ID="lbError" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

C#:

```
protected void btnGetValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbError.Text = gvCalc.Rows[0].Cells[0].ToString(); 
    //lbError RETURNS 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell' 
    //I DONT WANT THAT...I WANT THE VALUE
}
```

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error for this? What result are you getting, and what result are you expecting?

Comment: this code returns 'null' .... GridView grd = (GridView)this.FindControl("gvCalculos");

Comment: I think when you're calling `this` it's referencing your button. And thus there would be no `Control` object that is part of it.

Comment: Why can't you just access the GridView directly? lbResult.Text = gvHello.Rows....

Comment: i made what you suggested, i almost fix it...i edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TableCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell(v=vs.110).aspx) has a property [Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.text(v=vs.110).aspx) which contains the contents of the `Cell`.

Use

```
grd.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text;
```

instead of

```
grd.Rows[0].Cells[0].ToString();
```

Comment: this code returns 'null' .... GridView grd = (GridView)this.FindControl("gvCalculos");

Comment: Is it winform or asp.net?

Comment: Make sure you have given an `id` to the `GridView`. Aren't you adding it dynamically (at runtime)?

Comment: the id is ok, and the grid is not dinamic :(